Add CC or BCC email addresses dynamically when submitting a Elementor form, through the WordPress functions.php file
I am currently trying to dynamically add CC email addresses to an Elementor form through the WordPress functions.php file, but I can't seem to figure it out how. My client wants me to only add the CC email addresses when a specific value from a drop down / select field is selected. Not for the whole form.
I am able to program the logic when it should add the CC email addresses, but I can't figure out which Elementor Hook I should use and how to instruct it to add the CC emails. Any help is greatly appreciated.
At the moment I don't have a code example of what I tried because nothing really worked. I am still in the process of trying to figure out if it can even be done and if yes, how I will need to go about it.

The recipients (direct ones, and CC:/BCC:), are properties of the form itself, if I am not mistaken. I don't see any of the hooks mentioned on https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/forms/ getting anything like a "form instance" that you could manipulate passed in though. [...]

[...] You would have to use the "Form Mail Headers Filter" to inject your CC: recipient, I suppose - but the callback for that hook only gets the already existing headers passed in, but not the "record" the current submission will create. So I guess you'd have to figure out which value was actually submitted for the deciding select field, by directly looking at the content of $_POST.

Thanks a lot for your help. You pointed me in the right direction to get it to work.

By taking a closer look at the Elementor Forms API documentation, I made use of the elementor_pro/forms/process and elementor_pro/forms/wp_mail_headers hooks, and managed to get it to work.
Here is what I did:
##############################################################################
// Action is called when the forms is submitted and being processed
##############################################################################
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/process', 'add_cc_emails_to_submitted_elementor_forms', 10, 2 );
function add_cc_emails_to_submitted_elementor_forms( $record, $handler ) {
    // Get the form name
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
    
    // Check which form is being processed
    if ( $form_name !== 'FORM NAME') {
        return;
    }

    // Create an array of all the fields used in the form
    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    
    // Get the selected drop down value
    $drop_down_field_value = $raw_fields['field_name']['value'];
    
    // Set the CC email addresses
    if( $drop_down_field_value === 'SOMETHING' ){   
        // Call the filter to apply the needed CC Emails
        add_filter( 'elementor_pro/forms/wp_mail_headers', 'add_cc_emails_to_elementor_form', 10, 1 );
    }
}

##############################################################################
// Add CC email addresses to the Email Header
##############################################################################
function add_cc_emails_to_elementor_form( $headers ) {
    
    // Set all the CC email addresses   
    $headers .= "Cc: something@email.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Cc: something2@email.com\r\n";
    
    return $headers;
}

